# python array creation syntax [for in range]

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I came across the following syntax to create a python array. It is strange to me.

Can anyone explain it to me? And how should I learn this kind of syntax?

```
[str(index) for index in range(100)]
```

Comment: google "list comprehension in python".

Answer (score 10):

First of all, this is not an array. This is a list. Python does have built-in arrays, but they are rarely used (google the `array` module, if you're interested). The structure you see is called list comprehension. This is the fastest way to do vectorized stuff in pure Python. Let's get through some examples.

Simple list comprehensions are written this way:
`[item for item in iterable]` - this will build a list containing all items of an iterable.

Actually, you can do something with each item using an expression or a function: `[item**2 for item in iterable]` - this will square each element, or `[f(item) for item in iterable]` - f is a function.

You can even add `if` and `else` statements like this `[number for number in xrange(10) if not number % 2]` - this will create a list of even numbers; `['even' if not number % 2 else 'odd' for number in range(10)]` - this is how you use else statements.

You can nest list comprehensions `[[character for character in word] for word in words]` - this will create a list of lists. List comprehensions are similar to `generator expressions`, so you should google Python docs for additional information.

List comprehensions and generator expressions are among the most powerful and valuable Python features. Just start an interactive session and play for a while.

P.S.

There are other types of comprehensions that create sets and dictionaries. They use the same concept. Google them for additional information.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension itself is concept derived from mathematics' set comprehension, where to get new set, you specify parent set and the rule to filter out its elements.

In its simplest but full form list comprehension looks like this:

```
[f(i) for i in range(1000) if i % 2 == 0]
```

`range(1000)` - set of values you iterates through. It could be any iterable (list, tuple etc). `range` is just a function, which returns list of consecutive numbers, e.g. `range(4) -> [0, 1, 2, 3]`

`i` - variable will be assigned on each iteration.

`if i%2 == 0` - rule condition to filter values. If condition is not True, resulting list will not contain this element.

`f(i)` - any python code or function on `i`, result of which will be in resulting list.

For understand concept of list comprehensions, try them out in python console, and look at output. Here is some of them:

```
[i for i in [1,2,3,4]]
[i for i in range(10)]
[i**2 for i in range(10)]
[max(4, i) for i in range(10)]
[(1 if i>5 else -1) for i in range(10)]
[i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to unwrap all comprehensions you face into for-loops to better understand their mechanics and syntax until you get used to them. For example, your comprehension can be unwrapped this way:

```
newlist = []
for index in range(100)
    newlist.append(str(index))
```

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Why do you suggest such thing?

Comment: Because it simpler to understand it in this way...at least for me.

Comment: Simple list comprehensions (like the one above) are as clear - if not clearer - as for-loops, left alone how much faster they are. The advice should be to use them as much as you can, if it doesn't harm readability.

Comment: Not sure if they are faster or slower but simple list comprehensions that just build a list(like this one) are more readable. Also, they look beautiful... these kind of things make everybody love python.

Comment: I don't think, there is thing like "long representation of list comprehension". Your code does the same, but it is loop notation.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that when you're learning how to use list comprehension, better represent it with a loop and after you completely understand how it can be "represent" in a loop, you good to go with list comprehension.

Comment: @Artem Then you should rewrite your post to reflect this idea. Right now it looks like you suggest to avoid list comprehensions.